# .net 6.0 return application/rtf on api request programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I have a endpoint in my .net 6.0 project that needs to return a text either wrapped in a JSON or as RTF ( content type: application/RTF)

Weither or not JSON or RTF is returned is dependent on some data in a DB. My controller is returning an IActionResult and by default formatting as a JSON.

I don't really have a clue how I can set the return type programmatically.
Any advice ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to control that.
you should just return data

```
// json
return Ok(jsonData);

// rtf
return Ok(rtfData);
```

[image: Microsoft Docs]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Well exactly that's what I don't want. That would wrap my RTF into a Json. But I would like to return a application/rtf